# How to improve the performance of my model with Keras Conv1D and Maxpooling1D

Tags: python, keras, max-pooling

I work on the data of `Facebook Babi Task`, and after using the model with LSTM (as defined on this github https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/babi_rnn.py ). Now I want to use a model with convolution and Maxpooling to learn. But the performance is low and I would like to know if anyone has an idea to improve it.

```
embed_size = 50
batch_size=32
epochs=60
kernel_size = 3
pool_size = 2
strid = 1

story_model2 = Sequential()
    # input layers and convolutional layers
story_model2.add(Embedding(vocab_size,embed_size,input_length=story_max))
story_model2.add(Conv1D(embed_size, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=strid, padding='valid', activation='relu'))
story_model2.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=pool_size))
story_model2.add(Dropout(.5))
story_model2.summary()


question_model2 = Sequential()
    # input layers and convolutional layers
question_model2.add(Embedding(vocab_size,embed_size,input_length=question_max))
question_model2.add(Conv1D(embed_size, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=strid, padding='valid', activation='relu'))
question_model2.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=pool_size))
question_model2.add(Dropout(.5))
question_model2.summary()


mergedOut = Add()([story_model2.output,question_model2.output])
mergedOut = Flatten()(mergedOut)    
mergedOut = Dropout(.5)(mergedOut)
mergedOut = Dense(vocab_size, activation='relu')(mergedOut)
mergedOut = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')(mergedOut)

newModel = Model([story_model2.input,question_model2.input], mergedOut)
newModel.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.01),loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
newModel.fit([X, Xq], Y, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
```

The acc value of learning decreases

```
Epoch 1/60
1000/1000 [==============================] - 3s 3ms/step - loss: 2.0393 - acc: 0.1710
Epoch 2/60
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 452us/step - loss: 1.7408 - acc: 0.2420
Epoch 3/60
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 341us/step - loss: 1.6526 - acc: 0.3020
Epoch 4/60
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1s 529us/step - loss: 1.6301 - acc: 0.3400
Epoch 5/60
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1s 629us/step - loss: 1.5853 - acc: 0.3420
Epoch 6/60
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 474us/step - loss: 1.5693 - acc: 0.3630
Epoch 7/60
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 401us/step - loss: 1.5620 - acc: 0.3440
Epoch 8/60
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1s 966us/step - loss: 1.5468 - acc: 0.3540
Epoch 9/60
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 458us/step - loss: 1.4980 - acc: 0.3870
Epoch 10/60
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 428us/step - loss: 1.5259 - acc: 0.3700
Epoch 11/60
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 378us/step - loss: 1.5112 - acc: 0.3760
Epoch 12/60
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 374us/step - loss: 1.4929 - acc: 0.3810
....
```

My model returns as performance:

```
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step
Perte =  1.54148875618
Précision =  0.342
```

Comment: In your example your accuracy is increasing...

Comment: So in your opinion there is no way to improve more than that. just over 50%

Comment: No i was just pointing out that accuracy of your model rises from .17 to .38 in your example but you also said that the accuracy value was decreasing

Answer (score 0):

Your dropout may be too high. Try without it, just to compare.